# Metal top gaming mouse?

Tags: gaming, mice

I'm looking for a gaming mouse with a metal top. The more metal and less plastic the better. I have look all over the internet and found nothing. Metal bottom doesn't matter. I don't want a metal look, it must actually be metal. It doesn't HAVE to be a gaming mouse but it would be prefered. I don't want to spend too much money on a mouse so if it can be under $40 that would be great. I'm in canada so it would need to ship there. Please not wireless.

Comment: I haven't heard or seen such a product either. I think it would be more difficult and therefore expensive to manufacture. Do you have a specific use case for this? The only thing that comes close as far as I can think of is Apple's Magic Mouse 2 with a metal bottom and a glass top trackpad (at least it felt like glass). It's not made for gaming (can't use the mouse while charging) and I think more professional gamers would trade an all metal mouse with more weight for a lighter mouse with customizable weight.

Comment: Metal mouse are great but do remember that if you have a cold weather, possibly you will have a cold mouse. So probably use less metal

Comment: Same as @LiveWireBT, I'm confused as to why you want a metal mouse. Typically, plastics are used as lightness is often valued in mice; AFAIK the Magic Mouse is one of the few 'quality' (though rather unergonomic) mice which uses a primarily metal construction.

Answer (score 1):

I found one mouse that features a *"Lightweight Aluminum Chassis"*. If the buttons are metal or some form of polymer I can't say.

But whatever the case the [cyborg R.A.T. 7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003CP0BHM) is way over your limit of 40$.

Comment: All the mive like this claim to have it or have very little metal, but are all plastic inside.

Answer (score 0):

Genesis gx75 was a metal mouse, and in my opinion it is the best mouse that has ever been created. Miles ahead any Razer or Logitech mouse in terms of quality build. I got it for just 30€, but I would pay now a 100€ just to get another one.